# Formula de Saldos acumulados Crystal Report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sap

Estoy queriendo generar un campo en mi reporte de Crystal que me calcule el saldo acumulado según los pagos que van realizando, básicamente el total - 1er pago = saldo1 - 2do pago = saldo2 y así sucesivamente en cada registro.
Adjunto una imagen de mi ejemplo y como debería quedar, en verde los datos que tengo, y en amarillo el dato que deseo obtener.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siendo Mis Campos `CuotaUSD - appliedUSD = SaldoUSD`

Básicamente seria usar la función de **Insertar -> Total Acumulado** sobre el campo **SaldoUSD**

[image: Total Acumulado]

Ubicar en la sección Detalle del Reporte de esta manera evalúa por cada registro.
[image: Campo Saldo Acumulado]